# Recyclerview Adapter Viewtype for LazyColumn compose Android

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Please see XML based example:

```
 override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_ONE) {
        return GfgViewOne(
            LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.gfgParentOne, parent, false)
        )
    }
    return View2ViewHolder(
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_view_2, parent, false)
    )
}
```

So, Recyclerview Adapter I can inflate multiple viewtype, similarly how can I do in compose?

I tried this: one item below another, but I don't think this is right way

```
LazyColumn(
    state = listState,
    contentPadding = paddingValues
) {
    shopDataList?.let {
        
        items(count = shopDataList.size) { index ->
            val item: Item = it.get(index)

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.size(16.dp))
            RectangleImageCardList(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(horizontal = 16.dp)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .wrapContentWidth(),
                item = item
            )
        }

        items(count = shopDataList.size) { index ->
            val item: Item = it.get(index)

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.size(16.dp))
            RectangleImageCardList(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(horizontal = 16.dp)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .wrapContentWidth(),
                item = item
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Handle multiple view types in a LazyColumn in JetpackCompose as below-

```
LazyColumn(
            state = listState,
            contentPadding = paddingValues
        ) {
            items(shopDataList) { item ->
                when (item.viewType) {
                    VIEW_TYPE_ONE -> {
                        GfgViewOne(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .padding(horizontal = 16.dp)
                                .fillMaxWidth()
                                .wrapContentWidth(),
                            item = item
                        )
                    }
                    VIEW_TYPE_TWO -> {
                        View2(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .padding(horizontal = 16.dp)
                                .fillMaxWidth()
                                .wrapContentWidth(),
                            item = item
                        )
                    }
                    // Add more cases for different view types
                    else -> {
                       // Handle default view type if not found
                    }
                }
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.size(16.dp))
            }
        }
```